# More elegant way to route gclid google parameter in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

For google analytics, and to match the websearch parameters correctly on the keyword strategies, i want to make sure the google supplied gclid parameter gets passed on when redirects happen in the controller.

The reason for the redirect is to do split testing, and A/B testing on landingpages, as well as vanity urls matching the campaign themes better.

Currently - this is the way I "Hack" it:

```
    public class ArtclassController : Controller
    {
    //
    // GET: /Artclass/
    public ActionResult Kid(string gclid)
    {
        string _glcid = gclid;
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "ArtClassesForKids", new {glcid= _glcid  });
    }
```

My question is - is there a way to do this more elegantly? For instance, in the MVC routing?

(For brevities sake, in the supplied code example I have left out a second redirect, and the random function to choose a different landing page.)

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that there is a way, though you might be able to get away with using `Session` or even `TempData` to accomplish your mission.

Wherever `gclid` is determined in your code now use:

```
Session["gclid"] = gclid;
```

Wherever `gclid` is needed use:

```
gclid = Session["gclid"];
```

Comment: I am trying to understand - do you mean parking the value of the gclid in a session, like a cookie?